# AMPScript for REST API call in landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, landing-page

I'm trying to call REST API to display a push message that is sent from Marketing Cloud in landing page.

How do I call the API? I was able to get the Token using the client secret and ID but how to pass the token to the REST push message call.

How to pass the Authorization : Bearer TOKEN to the httpget call?

```
%%[
VAR @httppost,@apiid,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse,@apitoken
SET @apiid = '{"clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx","clientSecret": "xxxxxxxxx"}'
SET @httppost = HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken","application/json",@apiid,false,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse)
SET @apitoken = Substring(@apistatusCode,17,24)

VAR @httpgetmessage, @apiid,@apistatusCode2,@apiresponsemessage

SET @httppostmessage = HTTPGet("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/message/xxxxxxxx", headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + @apitoken,@apiresponsemessage})

%%=(@apitoken)=%% // This is printing my response token from the rest call

]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it done this way.  May not be the exact call for your case, but the structure would be similar.

```
%%[

  VAR @auth,@url,@returnCode,@response,@regex,@accessToken,@mobileNumber,@shortCode,@message,@QueueMO
  set @mobileNumber = "19135551212"
  set @shortCode = "99999"
  set @message = "STOP"
  SET @auth = '{"clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","clientSecret":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}'
  SET @url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken'
  SET @returnCode = HTTPPOST(@url,"application/json",@auth,@response)
  outputline(concat("<br>returnCode:", @returnCode))

  IF @returnCode = =  200 THEN
      SET @regex = '^{"accessToken":"(.*)",.*$'
      SET @accessToken = REGEXMATCH(@response,@regex,1)
      outputline(concat("<br>accessToken:", @accessToken))
      SET @QueueMO = CONCAT('{"mobileNumbers":["',@mobileNumber,'"],"ShortCode":',@shortCode,',"MessageText":"',@message,'"}')
      SET @url = CONCAT("https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/QueueMO/?access_token = ",@accessToken)
      SET @returnCode = HTTPPOST(@url,"application/json",@QueueMO,@response)
      outputline(concat("<br>returnCode:", @returnCode))
  ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: I'm not trying to send a push message, I need to display a push message sent to a contact in the landing page using the subscriber key.