# Shorten URL for SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

Referring to [MC documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/) I am trying to shorten a long URL using bitly. I have created an account in bitly and getting an API key from my personal account. But when I trigger the SMS, it did not get send out. I have no clue of the error.

```
%%[ 
VAR @URL, @longURL, @bitlyUrl, @msg
SET @URL = "example.com"
SET @msg = "Please click HERE" 
SET @longURL = CONCAT(@URL,"?id=",@subscriberKey)
SET @bitlyUrl = HTTPGet(Concat("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&format=txt&longUrl=",@longURL))
SET @msg = Replace(@msg,"HERE", @bitlyUrl) 
]%% 
%%=v(@msg)=%%
```

The Ampscript works if I don't shorten the URL with bitly. What is wrong here?

Btw [Is there any way to shorten URL in SMS in Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161050/is-there-any-way-to-shorten-url-in-sms-in-marketing-cloud/161055#161055) this solution is also not working for me.

Comment: Use google shortner to create bitly link

Comment: @Rohit Mourya does Google Shortner support dynamic link? I can't seem to find the documentation in MC help page.

Comment: I guess so.. Once you've constructed your final URL send to google shortner API and you'll get a bitly link

Comment: You'll need to get an access token from `bit.ly` before the HTTPGet().   Here's an example of getting an access token with AMPScript: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/171165/5202