# How to use ampscript from Marketing Cloud to make a callout to salesforce rest api?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, callout, rest

Anyone know how to use ampscript from Marketing Cloud to make a callout to salesforce rest api?

The REST API I need to call from ampscript is listed below:

/services/data/v45.0/query?q=SELECT ID , (SELECT ID, Data_Centre__C FROM OrderItems) FROM ORDER WHERE PrimaryContact__C = '0037F00001I2cxVQAR'

Comment: Where would this code be running?  In a CloudPage?

Comment: If so this question has been answered several times before.  Here's one example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/171165/5202

Comment: Yes, in a CloudPage. I have seen the example but that one is used to call the Marketing Cloud API (exacttargetapis) not Sales Colud REST API.